# ExtJS 6.5.3.57 Form Field Validator Function not firing

Tags: validation, extjs6, extjs6.5

I'm trying to add a validator to a form field in ExtJS 6.5.3.57 Classic or Modern. I thought from reading various posts that this should work, but when I run `myField.isValid()` it always returns true, and I don't see my `console.log()` statement firing so I have to assume my function isn't getting called.

```
{xtype: numberfield,
 name: 'myField',
 validator: function(field){
    console.log('testing my validator');
    return false;
  }
}
```

I also tried this as I wasn't sure if it was `validator` or `validators`

```
{xtype: numberfield,
 name: 'myField',
 validators: {
    fn: function(field){
            console.log('testing my validator');
            return false;
        }
  }
}
```

Am I wrong in thinking this should work?

Here's a fiddle showing that the top field in the login form which has a validator on it but never seems to log a message to the screen or console.  https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2eoa

Answer (score 1):

The second example you gave is valid, I've made a working [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2enh):

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype: 'textfield',
            validators: {
                fn: function(v) {
                    return v === 'abc' || 'Value must be abc'
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I forked an MVVM fiddle and added a validator field to the login screen which uses the same code that your example does, however the validator function never fires.  Is this an MVVM thing, or a form thing, where these validators don't work properly?  https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2enq

Comment: The versions are way different, my fiddle uses 6.5.3 modern, yours is using 6.0.2 classic, so... you should probably clarify.

Comment: Oh OK I didn't realize.  I'm actually developing in 6.5.3 modern too and still can't get it to fire that verifier.  I'll see if I can update the fiddle to show my problem

Comment: For simplicity sake I kept it in the classic framework but upgraded to 6.5.3.57, and still can't get the validator to fire.  https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2eoa

Comment: Because the modern and classic frameworks are different. There is 0 point you making a fiddle using classic.

Comment: My thought was, if I can't even get it to work in classic, I won't be able to make it work in modern.

Comment: The APIs are not the same, so the equivalence doesn't make sense.